# Redirect to index,php

Tags: php

i have been doing a register form for my website but i found me on a trouble.

This is my register form code(PHP File)

```
    <?php
include("../libraries/Security.php");
include("../includes/utils.inc");

$host = "localhost";
$userSQL = "root";
$pwSQL = "";
$db = "upbyte";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$userSQL,$pwSQL,$db);

$username = Security::xss_clean($_POST['username']);
$name = Security::xss_clean($_POST['name']);
$email = Security::xss_clean($_POST['email']);
$password = Security::xss_clean($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$insert = "INSERT INTO users(name,username,password,email) VALUES('$name','$username',md5('$password'),'$email')";

if(isset($_POST['Register'])){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        echo "Sorry...This email already exist..";
    }

    if(empty($username) && empty($name)&& empty($password)&& empty($email)) {
        print('Fill all the fields!');
    }else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            echo "Sorry...This email already exist..";
    }else{
        mysqli_query($con,$insert);
        echo "Register Completed!";
        utils::redirectToUrl("../index.php");
    }


} ?>
```

Its all good now, but when i submit the register form this redirect me to this:
"http://localhost/upbyte/App/index.php" and i just want redirect to: http://localhost/upbyte/index.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends, if there is a file called index.php before the App directory in upbite, you're probably just pointing it to the wrong file location.
Try changing the link from 
    `utils::redirectToUrl("../index.php");`
to
    `utils::redirectToUrl("/../index.php");`
You probably missed an index

Comment: @TomasAlmeida No problem :) Just a question: Português?

Comment: `/../` makes no sense. `/` means the root folder, and `../` means to go up one level. But you can't go up from the root.

Comment: @Barmar Has always worked for me, and apparently just worked for OP too

Comment: I think the browser just ignores extra `../`, so it's equivalent to `/index.php`.

Comment: @Barmar Makes sense, well today I learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: @ ImInThatCorner yap portugues xD

Answer (score 1):

You can use `header();` to redirect a user,

to do a timed redirect,

`exit(header("Refresh: $time; URL=$page"));`

to do an instant redirect,

`exit(header("Location: $page"));`

**Reading Material**

[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: He **is** being redirected, but to a file in the wrong folder. Presumably his `utils::redirectToUrl` function performs this `header()` call.

Comment: @Barmar yes my function is performing header :D